Tkinter window freezes after increasing the width of the line
Tkinter window freezes after increasing the width of the line. i am tried few times and the screen freezes always. if i use smaller width it works. however, some line thicknesses are different from each other.
if it set "default_object_width" to lesser value it works.
import tkinter as tk

def create_circle(x, y, r, canvas): #center coordinates, radius
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)


class MainProgram:

    default_object_width = 5
    default_object_fill_color = "black"
    default_object_selection_width = 4
    default_object_selection_color = "red"

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width = 400, height = 400, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        point_list = (20,20), (50,75), (75,100), (100,125), (125,60)
        point = 0
        while point < len(point_list):
            startpoint = point_list[point]
            point = point + 1
            if point < len(point_list):
                endpoint = point_list[point]
                self.canvas.create_line(startpoint, endpoint, tags="object", fill=self.default_object_fill_color, width = self.default_object_width)
                create_circle(endpoint[0], endpoint[1], 5, self.canvas)
                startpoint = endpoint

        # Bind mouse events
        self.canvas.tag_bind("object", "<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("object", "<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, event):
        # Get the current color of the line
        self.current_color = self.canvas.itemcget("object", "fill")
        self.current_width = self.canvas.itemcget("object", "width")
        # Change the color to red
        self.canvas.itemconfig(tk.CURRENT, fill= self.default_object_selection_color,  width = self.default_object_selection_width)

    def on_leave(self, event):
        # Restore the original color
        self.canvas.itemconfig(tk.CURRENT, fill=self.current_color, width = self.current_width)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainProgram(root)
    root.mainloop()


Changing the line width in callbacks for <Enter> and <Leave> events is not a good design as <Leave> event may be triggered inside callback of <Enter> and vice versa, which may result in infinite loop.

ine 49, in on_leave
self.canvas.itemconfig(tk.CURRENT, fill=self.current_color, width = self.current_width)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MainProgram' object has no attribute 'current_color'

@acw1668 i am new to python. i will try to find a different way. thank you so much

Canvas items have activefill and activewidth options. self.canvas.create_line(..., activefill="red", activewidth=4).

Yes, I noticed it after some time. Thank you so much for the link. it is really helpful to me.
